# Does emission-spectrum of molecule equal sum of emission-spectrum of its components

Tags: spectroscopy, molecules, photon-emission, elements

Imagine a number of **elements** with known **emission-spectra**, that form a primary **chemical bond** of either
* ionic
* covalent
* metallic
type.
Does the emission-spectrum of the resulting **molecule** match the sum of spectra of its components(the elements)?
Why/Why not?

Comment: Atoms have their distinctive spectra molecules have extra transitions to their components. see https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/21Spectra_and_Structure_of_Atoms_and_Molecules/21.05%3A_The_Visible_and_Ultraviolet_Spectra_of_Molecules%3A_Molecular_Orbitals

Comment: Since the molecule is a bunch of atoms stuck together using their electrons, why would it seem unusual for those electrons to now have different energy levels?